# WCF Webservice DataContract array

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract

Hi all i been trying searching the internet for very long, but no answer to this.

i need to get this.

```
<main>
    <Reason>
          <TypeA>mystringA</TypeA>
          <TypeB>mystringB</TypeB>
    </Reason>
    <Reason>
          <TypeA>mystringA</TypeA>
          <TypeB>mystringB</TypeB>
    </Reason>
</main>
```

but i get getting this

```
<main>
    <Reasons>
        <Reason>
              <TypeA>mystringA</TypeA>
              <TypeB>mystringB</TypeB>
        </Reason>
        <Reason>
              <TypeA>mystringA</TypeA>
              <TypeB>mystringB</TypeB>
        </Reason>
    </Reasons>
</main>
```

this is my DataContract Clas

```
[DataContract]
public partial class Reason{
     [DataMember]
     public string TypeA {get; set;}

     [DataMember]
     public string TypeB {get; set;}
}

[DataContract]
public partial class main{

    [DataMember]
    public Reason[] Reasons {get; set;}
}
```

i tried [CollctionDataContract] etc, but cant get what i need
how do i remove away my "Reasons"?

Comment: There is no direct way to achieve this when using `DataContract`. A solution is to implement `IMessageInspector` to modify the raw xml after serialization. See [here for an implementation of the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10498954/643318)

Comment: Hi thanks :) will look into modifying the xml :)