# WCF Soap service accept specific contract definition

Tags: wcf, soap

I have this request to fit with a wcf service:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sen="http://sender.v1.datineo.push.ws.nicbase.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sen:PushDataArray>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <pushDataArray>
            <assetId>?</assetId>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <assetName>?</assetName>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <boxData>
               <boxId>?</boxId>
               <provider>?</provider>
               <gateway>?</gateway>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <timestamp>?</timestamp>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <timeReceived>?</timeReceived>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <gpsData>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <timestamp>?</timestamp>
                  <latitude>?</latitude>
                  <longitude>?</longitude>
    
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <location>?</location>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <height>?</height>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <direction>?</direction>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <heading>?</heading>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <distance>?</distance>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <totalDistance>?</totalDistance>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <speed>?</speed>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <satellites>?</satellites>
               </gpsData>
            </boxData>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <externalCustomerIdentification>?</externalCustomerIdentification>
         </pushDataArray>
      </sen:PushDataArray>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

At now i produce:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sen="http://sen.company.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sen:datineoV1>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <sen:datineoV1Data>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <sen:PushDataArray>
               <assetId>?</assetId>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <assetName>?</assetName>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <boxData>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <boxId>?</boxId>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <provider>?</provider>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <gateway>?</gateway>
                  <timestamp>?</timestamp>
                  <timeReceived>?</timeReceived>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <gpsData>
                     <timestamp>?</timestamp>
                     <latitude>?</latitude>
                     <longitude>?</longitude>
                     <height>?</height>
                     <!--Optional:-->
                     <location>?</location>
                     <direction>?</direction>
                     <heading>?</heading>
                     <distance>?</distance>
                     <totalDistance>?</totalDistance>
                     <speed>?</speed>
                     <satellites>?</satellites>
                  </gpsData>
               </boxData>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <externalCustomerIdentification>?</externalCustomerIdentification>
            </sen:PushDataArray>
         </sen:datineoV1Data>
      </sen:datineoV1>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here the Interface:

```
namespace TA_service_library
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://sen.company.com")]
    [XmlSerializerFormat]
    public interface IDataImportSoapService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            UriTemplate = "datineoV1", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        DatineoV1Response datineoV1(PushDataArray[] datineoV1Data);
        //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class DatineoV1Response
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "status", Namespace = ""), MessageBodyMember]
        public bool status { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace TA_service_library.Model
{
    [Serializable]
    public class PushDataArray
    {
        public class GpsData
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "timestamp", Namespace = ""), MessageBodyMember]
            public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "latitude", Namespace = ""), MessageBodyMember]
            public double latitude { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "longitude", Namespace = ""), MessageBodyMember]
            public double longitude { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "height", Namespace = ""), MessageBodyMember]
            public int height { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "location", Namespace = ""), MessageBodyMember]
            public string location { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "direction", Namespace = ""), MessageBodyMember]
            public int direction { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "heading", Namespace = ""), MessageBodyMember]
            public int heading { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "distance", Namespace = ""), MessageBodyMember]
            public int distance { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "totalDistance", Namespace = ""), MessageBodyMember]
            public int totalDistance { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "speed", Namespace = ""), MessageBodyMember]
            public double speed { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "satellites", Namespace = ""), MessageBodyMember]
            public int satellites { get; set; }
        }

        public class BoxData
        {

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "boxId", Namespace = ""), MessageBodyMember]
            public string boxId { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "provider", Namespace = ""), MessageBodyMember]
            public string provider { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "gateway", Namespace = ""), MessageBodyMember]
            public string gateway { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "timestamp", Namespace = ""), MessageBodyMember]
            public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "timeReceived", Namespace = ""), MessageBodyMember]
            public DateTime timeReceived { get; set; }

            [XmlElement(ElementName = "gpsData", Namespace = ""), MessageBodyMember]
            public GpsData gpsData { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "assetId", Namespace = ""), MessageBodyMember]
        public int assetId { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "assetName", Namespace = ""), MessageBodyMember]
        public string assetName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "boxData", Namespace = ""), MessageBodyMember]
        public BoxData boxData { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "externalCustomerIdentification", Namespace = ""), MessageBodyMember]
        public string externalCustomerIdentification { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Any advices? I use XmlSerializer for more flexibility and because i think the problem should be this:

[WCF Serialize Array or Collection Without a Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685807/wcf-serialize-array-or-collection-without-a-container)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to say. Your problem is how to serialize your code better?

Comment: @Jiayao No, I would like to understand where I am wrong in defining the code above for me to map the contract shown in the first piece of code...

Comment: You can try to modify yours based on his code.